# How to filter out

Tags: django

I have a problem in Django template, here is my current code:

```
<h1 id="django">{{module.headline}}</h1>
```

It displays something like:

```
"My name is Alex"
```

Please suggest me code for Django template filter for this particular problem.

Comment: Also next time, please show us what you have tried instead of beg for free code.

Comment: What did you try yourself?

Comment: Maybe it's me but what exactly is the question?

Comment: What is the Problem here ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create [your own custom filte](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#registering-custom-filters)r to be efficient:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def emph_first_word(value):
    if not value:
        return ""

    value = value.split(' ', 1)
    return "<em>{}</em> {}".format(*value)
```

And then use it like this:

```
<h1 id="django">{{ module.headline|emph_first_word }}</h1>
```

... which should return (for your example):

```
<h1 id="django"><em>My</em> name is Varun</h1>
```